# How to receive message as notification when the android chat application is in background

Tags: android, socket.io

I am working on an android instant chat application. I have implemented it using socket.io-client library.Everything is working fine here .Messages can be sent from one user to another using socket when the application is going to be used by different user on different devices.But this is possible only when the application is active.If the application is not active on the other end,it is not working properly.I want to notify the user that the message has arrived as WatsApp does.How can i achieve this using sockets.

**Following is the code of my Listener:**

```
 mSocket.on("send:notice", onReceive); // Listening event for receiving messages

 // Event Listener for receiving messages
private Emitter.Listener onReceive = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        Log.e("Receive", "Bean_Message received");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                Log.e("DATA", String.valueOf(data));
                try {
                    JSONArray ops = data.getJSONArray("ops");
                    Log.e("JSONArray", ops.toString());
                    for (int i = 0; i < ops.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = ops.getJSONObject(i);
                        String roomID = object.getString("room_id");
                        Log.e("RoomID", roomID); // Getting room ID from JSON array
                        Log.e("Md5RoomID", md5StringRoomID); // Getting room id which we have created using logged in user ID and room id of the user through which chat has to be done
                        //Comparing the room IDs
                        if (md5StringRoomID.equals(roomID)) {
                            String senderName = object.getString("user");
                            Log.e("Sender Name", senderName);
                            String senderID = object.getString("id");
                            Log.e("SenderID", senderID);
                            String date = object.getString("date"); // Getting timestamp value in the form of string
                            long time = Long.parseLong(date); //Converting String into long
                            String t = getDateFromTimestamp(time); // Getting date and time from timestamp
                            Log.e("DateReceived", date);
                            // JSONObject message = object.getJSONObject("message");
                            String unicodeMessageReceived = object.getString("message");
                            Log.e("UnicodeMessageReceived", unicodeMessageReceived);
                            //Decoding unicode characters for emoji
                            String messageReceived = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(unicodeMessageReceived);
                            Log.e("DecodedMessageReceived", messageReceived);
                            String loggedInUSerNAme = sharedPreferences.getString(Prefs_Registration.get_user_name, null);
                            //String loggedInUSerNAme = almaChatDatabase.getUserName();
                            //If the message is sent by the owner to other from webapp ,then we need to check whether the sender is the loggedinUSer in the App or not and we will right align the messages .
                            if (loggedInUSerNAme.equalsIgnoreCase(senderName)) {
                                isSelf = true;
                                msg = new Bean_Message(senderName, messageReceived, isSelf);
                                msg.setMessageStatus(Status.SENT);
                                msg.setTime(t);
                                listBeanMessages.add(msg);
                                // Log.e("List Elements", String.valueOf(listBeanMessages));
                                adapter_message.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                playBeep();
                            } else {
                                isSelf = false;
                                msg = new Bean_Message(senderName, messageReceived, isSelf);
                                msg.setTime(t);
                                listBeanMessages.add(msg);
                                Log.e("List Elements", String.valueOf(listBeanMessages));
                                adapter_message.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                playBeep();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Playing sound when the message is sent by other
    public void playBeep() {
        try {
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

};
```

I have to handle two case for notification:
1. When the application is in background
2. When the application is in foreground but the user A is busy with user B when message from user C arrives.

Please help me to fix my issue .

Comment: Either you have create a background service and keep the connection alive with socket or you should use push notifications i.e if the other user is not connected to socket the server should send a push message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .Can you please send me some link to study?

Comment: I have implemented the same using push notification.

Comment: Please explain in detail.

Comment: what kind of detail you need about push notifications or about background services in android?

Comment: As i install the application ,i want the socket to be connected.How can i achieve this?

Comment: Create a background service as described here http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html , Write to socket connection code in this service and start the service from the launcher activity and use the service by binding to it from other activities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105789/discussion-between-deepakr-and-oone).

Comment: @O'one  Please tell me whether i have to use IntentService or BoundService or Service class for the implementing the concept.

Comment: Service not IntentService

Answer (score 3):

1. One way is
   you should run your own service with START_STICKY when your application start and inside that service you must start one thread. for reference please refer android documentation of service http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Service.html
2. Another way is by using MQTT OR Socket AND FCM push notification.

- Connect to socket.io server Or MQTT protocol server
  if the user opens the app make a connection and subscribe for events and disconnect once the user goes
  background from socket.io server or MQTT.
- if a user is disconnected from the socket.io server OR MQTT the fallback to FCM push notification the notify the user keep the same notification ids for bothe FMC and socket.io or MQTT so that you can ignore one of them during the proccesing.

Answer (score 1):

Create a background service as described here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html,
Write to socket connection code in this service and start the service from the launcher activity and use the service by binding to it from other activities

Comment: Please tell me whether i have to use IntentService or BoundService or Service class for the implementing the concept.

Comment: You have to use Service not IntentService. Service is also known as bound service

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Emitter.Listener handleIncomingMessages = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                String message = null;
                String imageText;
                try {
                    message = data.getString("message").toString();
                  Log.v("messageeeeeeeeeee",message);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // return;
                }

                addMessage(message);

                try {
                    imageText = data.getString("image");
                    addImage(decodeImage(imageText));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    //retur
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```